# conditional query with hibernate Composite(key) Object

Tags: hibernate

CREATE TABLE  `ratecodes` (
  `roomId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
..., PRIMARY KEY (`roomId`,`date`))
hbm.xml

```
<class catalog="hermes" name="com.hermes.data.RateCode" table="ratecodes">
<composite-id class="com.hermes.data.RateCodeId" name="id">
      <key-property name="roomId" type="int">
        <column name="roomId"/>
      </key-property>
      <key-property name="date" type="date">
        <column length="10" name="date"/>
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <version name="version" type="java.lang.Long">
      <column name="version" precision="10" scale="0"/>
    </version>
```

i want to query 
HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from RateCode where (RatecodeId (between|<) RateCodeId)"

SQL:
"from RateCode  where roomId = 3000 and date > :fromDate and date < :toDate"

RatecodeId.java  (composite)

```
public class RateCodeId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int roomId;
    private Date date;

    public RateCodeId() {
    }

    public RateCodeId(int roomId, Date date) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getRoomId() {
        return this.roomId;
    }

    public void setRoomId(int roomId) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((other == null)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof RateCodeId)) {
            return false;
        }
        RateCodeId castOther = (RateCodeId) other;

        return (this.getRoomId() == castOther.getRoomId())
                && ((this.getDate() == castOther.getDate()) || (this.getDate() != null && castOther.getDate() != null && this.getDate().equals(castOther.getDate())));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + this.getRoomId();
        result = 37 * result + (getDate() == null ? 0 : this.getDate().hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

how to set FromDate and Todate in Object and do condition of RateCodeID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String hql = "from RateCode rc where rc.id.roomId = 3000"
             + " and rc.id.date > :fromDate"
             + " and rc.id.date < :toDate";
Query q = session.createQuery(hql);
q.setParameter("fromDate", theFromDate);
q.setParameter("toDate", theToDate);
```